# I want to integrate a chat window/option into my web app. Where do I start?

Tags: java, jquery, angular, websocket, chat

I've made **a web-app for a school which gives teachers & management to interact with parents more easily**. I'm not a professional programmer, programming is my hobby. I did it more as free work for a school I know and I like creating stuff on my own. I use **JSP for rendering the HTML views** and used a bit of **jQuery for ajax functions**. The **user session is managed by servlets** and I use **MySQL as the database**. The app has all the regular school stuff such as student progress tracking, fees view,attendance and so-on. **One thing it doesn't have is chat** feature. I looked into the socket programming in some sites and some brief videos from YouTube. All it says are the basics, ie; how to create a server object and client object and make them listen to each other using console. Some other tutorials shows me how to create a group chat. **What I need is a sold guide or a tutorial that outlines the stuff for  making a regular chat application, when users login, they can select an account to chat with and start private chat (no fancy stuff).** I'm on my way to convert the entire front-end from jsp-html-js combo to Angular (Still learning from tutorials). So all your opinions, suggestions or any tutorial, website, book for this problem is greatly appreciated (**If the tutorials/library/books/suggestions are focused on angular, great ! I'm already converting my app to Angular**).

Side note - I'm not super good at back-end (Java). I'm going to solidify my skill Spring, Rest, Jax-Rs and all other stuff after I learn Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first. I'm glad you are leaving JSP that thing sucks.

Now, Welcome to the Angular world!

If you aren't very good at the backend you should take a look to firebase. That way you won't have to set up a sockets.io. Firebase is already a real time database.

Right here you can learn how to build a chat using firebase and angular.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKAXg2drQJQ

here's my code as well
https://github.com/devpato/fire-chat

LIVE demo: https://megachat-e414c.web.app/

Comment: Thank you good sir. Sources you've given me is fantastic. I'm definitely going to try that out. I have couple of doubts too, Isn't there some limits to Firebase, such as storage , no of users or number of push-thingies (don't know the exact term, still learning. LOL) . Also, the demo link you gave me doesn't let me sign into it, the sign in button pop up a window and the window keeps closing. I don't know if that is a bug or my browser problem. Tried it in chrome and EDGE (non chromium version).

Comment: I just posted the code to my repo on github. And I just try the chat, the first time I clicked signin I ran into that issue you mention looks like the google signin is hangin I can select my account but stays in there and that's handle by firebase. Anyway no there's not limit on the amount of data BUT if you exceed the free tier it will cost you (like any other database) In the github repo I have screenshots. fi this was helpful feel free to accept it as the answer